# How to allow selection of text by the user when cufon/sifr is used?

Tags: javascript, html, css, http, bookmarklet

Take this site for example where the main title: Working with Sessions and Cookies in PHP and MYSQL is with cufon.

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/working-with-sessions-and-cookies-in-php-and-mysql/

I need a way with Javascript (placed in a bookmarklet) to get that title as user selected, like if you would do an inspect. So the operation would be that user highlights the text and hits a button. But selection doesn't happen, and there is no text in DOM for that, only some cufon injected canvas stuff.

How would be possible?

Comment: Might not be possible, as only visible content can be selected, and cufon/sift hide the original HTML content afaik, and therefore it cannot be selected.

Answer (score 1):

Cufon replaces the text with an image, but there's text hidden behind it for screen readers and accessibility. You'll see it if you inspect element, so it is in the DOM. You might want to try changing its CSS so that it's positioned above or below the cufon text, maybe with opacity set to 0.01, so that it's not visible but it is selectable.

I haven't tried this myself but it's the first thing I'd attempt in that situation :)

Something like:

```
cufon cufontext {
  display: inline-block !important;
  height: 16px;
  overflow: visible;
  text-indent: 0;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 0.1;
  position: relative;
  top: -16px;
}
```

Comment: I am not the owner of the website, I am just doing the bookmarklet which can run on any site, and I need to make it possible the user to highlight the title.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. In that case I don't know really! The text is there but I don't know if you can alter what the user has selected. you can possibly apply the above css to all cufon on mousedown, then experiment with what gets selected. If the cufontext was to be brought in front of the cufon image it might be selected then instead of the image. Sounds like it will take a bit of experimentation either way. There's no quick solution that I know of :)